# SharePoint site workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a question, I have created a SharePoint workflow using designer and I need to run the workflow at the first of each month and it should check all the records created on that month. How can I achieve this?
Someone said I can achieve this using site workflow, however I cant find where I can say run at the first of each month?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint designer workflow, using 2013 workflow will be an option like this [blog](https://blog.ion.works/2019/01/09/how-to-do-workflows-in-sharepoint-part-3-scheduling-a-workflow/). You will need to construct a loop inside and there will not be an normal way to stop it.

If you are using SharePoint Online, it may be better to use Flow for recurring events